# How to read PDFs line by line in R?

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining

I was using read_pdf() function from pdftools package to read PDF files line by line, but suddenly without changing anything in the script, any argument or line, it started reading the whole page instead of separating the elements by line. How do I get it to go back to line by line separation? This is the only way I can use text mining to build the database I need.

Comment: The documentation for `read_pdf` from pdftools says "The pdf_text function renders all textboxes on a text canvas and returns a character vector of equal length to the number of pages in the PDF file." That is, it will return pages.  On the other hand, the function `read_pdf` from the package `textreadr` says "Returns a base::data.frame() with the page number (page_id), line number (element_id), and the text."   Are you sure that you weren't using `textreadr` before?

Comment: Yes I do, besides using the same script and files, it still returns a database with page_id and element_id, but now the element_id column does not specify the lines. And also the read_pdf from textreadr is "a wrapper for pdftools::pdf_text() to read PDFs into R.", both work in similar ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code, you can text line by line by reading the PDF file directly

```
library(pdftools)
library(pagedown)

chrome_print(input = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat", 
             output = "D:\\Text_PDF_Cat.pdf")

text <- pdf_text("D:\\Text_PDF_Cat.pdf")
text <- lapply(X = text, FUN = function(x) strsplit(x, "\n"))
text <- unlist(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, you can convert a PDF file to Word and save it as txt file afterwards. You can read the first line of the txt file afterwards :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(pagedown)

#############################################
#### Step 1 : Save wikipedia page as PDF ####
#############################################
chrome_print(input = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat", 
             output = "D:\\Text_PDF_Cat.pdf")

path_PDF <- "D:\\Text_PDF_Cat.pdf"
path_Word <- "D:\\Text_PDF_Cat.docx"
path_Txt <- "D:\\Text_PDF_Cat.txt"

################################################################
#### Step 2 : Convert PDF to word document with OCR of Word ####
################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)  # convert pdf file to word / an OCR is included in word
doc$SaveAs(path_Txt, FileFormat = 4) # Save file to txt

#########################################
#### Step 3 : Read first line of txt ####
#########################################
readLines(path_Txt, n = 1)
```